# Sprite wont spawn

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

This code spawns a monster, but no enemy.
I expect an enemy to be spawned, why doesn't it?

```
#import "MyScene.h"
#import "GameOverScene.h"

static const uint32_t projectileCategory     =  0x1 << 0;
static const uint32_t monsterCategory        =  0x1 << 1;
static const uint32_t enemyCategory        =  0x1 << 1;


// 1
@interface MyScene () <SKPhysicsContactDelegate>
@property (nonatomic) SKSpriteNode * player;
@property (nonatomic) NSTimeInterval lastSpawnTimeInterval;
@property (nonatomic) NSTimeInterval lastUpdateTimeInterval;
@property (nonatomic) int monstersDestroyed;
@property (nonatomic) int enemysDestroyed;
@end

static inline CGPoint rwAdd(CGPoint a, CGPoint b) {
     return CGPointMake(a.x + b.x, a.y + b.y);
}

static inline CGPoint rwSub(CGPoint a, CGPoint b) {
     return CGPointMake(a.x - b.x, a.y - b.y);
}

static inline CGPoint rwMult(CGPoint a, float b) {
     return CGPointMake(a.x * b, a.y * b);
}

static inline float rwLength(CGPoint a) {
     return sqrtf(a.x * a.x + a.y * a.y);
}

// Makes a vector have a length of 1
static inline CGPoint rwNormalize(CGPoint a) {
float length = rwLength(a);
return CGPointMake(a.x / length, a.y / length);
}

@implementation MyScene

-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {    
if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {

    // 2
    NSLog(@"Size: %@", NSStringFromCGSize(size));

    // 3
    self.backgroundColor = [SKColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:1.0 blue:1.0 alpha:1.0];


    // 4
    self.player = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"player"];
    self.player.position = CGPointMake(self.player.size.width/2, self.frame.size.height/2);
    [self addChild:self.player];

    self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0,0);
    self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self;

}
return self;
}

-(void)addMonster {

// Create sprite
SKSpriteNode * monster = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"monster"];
monster.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:monster.size]; // 1
monster.physicsBody.dynamic = YES; // 2
monster.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = monsterCategory; // 3
monster.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = projectileCategory; // 4
monster.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = 0; // 5

// Determine where to spawn the monster along the Y axis
int minY = monster.size.height / 2;
int maxY = self.frame.size.height - monster.size.height / 2;
int rangeY = maxY - minY;
int actualY = (arc4random() % rangeY) + minY;

// Create the monster slightly off-screen along the right edge,
// and along a random position along the Y axis as calculated above
monster.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width + monster.size.width/2, actualY);
[self addChild:monster];

// Determine speed of the monster
int minDuration = 2.0;
int maxDuration = 4.0;
int rangeDuration = maxDuration - minDuration;
int actualDuration = (arc4random() % rangeDuration) + minDuration;

// Create the actions
SKAction * actionMove = [SKAction moveTo:CGPointMake(-monster.size.width/2, actualY) duration:actualDuration];
SKAction * actionMoveDone = [SKAction removeFromParent];
SKAction * loseAction = [SKAction runBlock:^{
    SKTransition *reveal = [SKTransition flipHorizontalWithDuration:0.5];
    SKScene * gameOverScene = [[GameOverScene alloc] initWithSize:self.size won:NO];
    [self.view presentScene:gameOverScene transition: reveal];
}];
[monster runAction:[SKAction sequence:@[actionMove, loseAction, actionMoveDone]]];

}

- (void)updateWithTimeSinceLastUpdate:(CFTimeInterval)timeSinceLast {

     self.lastSpawnTimeInterval += timeSinceLast;
     if (self.lastSpawnTimeInterval > 1) {
         self.lastSpawnTimeInterval = 0;
         [self addMonster];
     }
}

- (void)update:(NSTimeInterval)currentTime {
    // Handle time delta.
    // If we drop below 60fps, we still want everything to move the same distance.
    CFTimeInterval timeSinceLast = currentTime - self.lastUpdateTimeInterval;
    self.lastUpdateTimeInterval = currentTime;
    if (timeSinceLast > 1) { // more than a second since last update
        timeSinceLast = 1.0 / 60.0;
        self.lastUpdateTimeInterval = currentTime;
    }

    [self updateWithTimeSinceLastUpdate:timeSinceLast];

}

-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

[self runAction:[SKAction playSoundFileNamed:@"pew-pew-lei.caf" waitForCompletion:NO]];

// 1 - Choose one of the touches to work with
UITouch * touch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];

// 2 - Set up initial location of projectile
SKSpriteNode * projectile = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"projectile"];
projectile.position = self.player.position;
projectile.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:projectile.size.width/2];
projectile.physicsBody.dynamic = YES;
projectile.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = projectileCategory;
projectile.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = monsterCategory;
projectile.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = enemyCategory;
projectile.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = 0;
projectile.physicsBody.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = YES;

// 3- Determine offset of location to projectile
CGPoint offset = rwSub(location, projectile.position);

// 4 - Bail out if you are shooting down or backwards
if (offset.x <= 0) return;

// 5 - OK to add now - we've double checked position
[self addChild:projectile];

// 6 - Get the direction of where to shoot
CGPoint direction = rwNormalize(offset);

// 7 - Make it shoot far enough to be guaranteed off screen
CGPoint shootAmount = rwMult(direction, 1000);

// 8 - Add the shoot amount to the current position       
CGPoint realDest = rwAdd(shootAmount, projectile.position);

// 9 - Create the actions
float velocity = 480.0/1.0;
float realMoveDuration = self.size.width / velocity;
SKAction * actionMove = [SKAction moveTo:realDest duration:realMoveDuration];
SKAction * actionMoveDone = [SKAction removeFromParent];
[projectile runAction:[SKAction sequence:@[actionMove, actionMoveDone]]];

}

- (void)projectile:(SKSpriteNode *)projectile didCollideWithMonster:(SKSpriteNode    *)monster {
NSLog(@"Hit");
[projectile removeFromParent];
[monster removeFromParent];
self.monstersDestroyed++;
if (self.monstersDestroyed > 80) {
    SKTransition *reveal = [SKTransition flipHorizontalWithDuration:0.5];
    SKScene * gameOverScene = [[GameOverScene alloc] initWithSize:self.size won:YES];
    [self.view presentScene:gameOverScene transition: reveal];
}
}

- (void)didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact
{
// 1
SKPhysicsBody *firstBody, *secondBody, *thirdBody;

if (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask < contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask)
{
    firstBody = contact.bodyA;
    secondBody = contact.bodyB;
    thirdBody = contact.bodyB;
}
else
{
    firstBody = contact.bodyB;
    secondBody = contact.bodyA;
    thirdBody = contact.bodyA;
}

// 2
if ((firstBody.categoryBitMask & projectileCategory) != 0 &&
    (secondBody.categoryBitMask & enemyCategory) != 0 &&
    (thirdBody.categoryBitMask & monsterCategory) != 0)
{
    [self projectile:(SKSpriteNode *) firstBody.node didCollideWithMonster:(SKSpriteNode         *) secondBody.node];

    [self projectile:(SKSpriteNode *) firstBody.node didCollideWithEnemy: (SKSpriteNode *)   secondBody.node];
}
}

 - (void)addEnemy {

// Create sprite
SKSpriteNode * enemy = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"enemy"];
enemy.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:enemy.size]; // 1
enemy.physicsBody.dynamic = YES; // 2
enemy.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = enemyCategory; // 3
enemy.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = projectileCategory; // 4
enemy.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = 0; // 5

// Determine where to spawn the monster along the Y axis
int minY = enemy.size.height / 2;
int maxY = self.frame.size.height - enemy.size.height / 2;
int rangeY = maxY - minY;
int actualY = (arc4random() % rangeY) + minY;

// Create the monster slightly off-screen along the right edge,
// and along a random position along the Y axis as calculated above
enemy.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width + enemy.size.width/2, actualY);
[self addChild:enemy];

// Determine speed of the monster
int minDuration = 1.0;
int maxDuration = 6.0;
int rangeDuration = maxDuration - minDuration;
int actualDuration = (arc4random() % rangeDuration) + minDuration;

// Create the actions
SKAction * actionMove = [SKAction moveTo:CGPointMake(-enemy.size.width/2, actualY)  duration:actualDuration];
SKAction * actionMoveDone = [SKAction removeFromParent];
SKAction * loseAction = [SKAction runBlock:^{
    SKTransition *reveal = [SKTransition flipHorizontalWithDuration:0.5];
    SKScene * gameOverScene = [[GameOverScene alloc] initWithSize:self.size won:NO];
    [self.view presentScene:gameOverScene transition: reveal];
}];
[enemy runAction:[SKAction sequence:@[actionMove, loseAction, actionMoveDone]]];
}

- (void)projectile:(SKSpriteNode *)projectile didCollideWithEnemy:(SKSpriteNode *)enemy {
    NSLog(@"Hit");
    [projectile removeFromParent];
    [enemy removeFromParent];
    self.enemysDestroyed++;
    if (self.enemysDestroyed > 80) {
    SKTransition *reveal = [SKTransition flipHorizontalWithDuration:0.5];
    SKScene * gameOverScene = [[GameOverScene alloc] initWithSize:self.size won:YES];
    [self.view presentScene:gameOverScene transition: reveal];

    }
}

@end
```

Comment: Why would an enemy ever spawn in this code ? Ask yourself, how does the monster spawn ?

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if you realize this, but you never actually call `addEnemy`. Look through the code. You will find a call to `addMonster` but never `addEnemy`. Implementing the method is one thing- without calling the method, whatever is inside will never run.

Comment: Agreed. @user3053675, you need to take a sheet of paper and draw the flow of your code. Read through your programming and draw it on the paper. You'll find out that you haven't told the computer what it needs to do, so it doesn't do it. Draw a flow.